# "An unexpected error occured" whenever I try "npx hardhat compile" in new project with hardhat 2.11.1

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have always an error whenever I try to compile the new hardhat project even though I use the default contract (Lock.sol) coming with hardhat. I didn't change anything.

1- I created a new hardhat JS project on cmd by using `npx hardhat`

2- I downloaded the packages that hardhat is recommend. `npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.11.1" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^1.0.1"`

3- I tried to compile `npx hardhat compile`

```
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\turgay\Desktop\SolidityProjects\emptyhardhatfinal\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc\solidity-analyzer.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\turgay\Desktop\SolidityProjects\emptyhardhatfinal\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer\index.js:69:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

My hardhat.config file:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
};
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hardhat-project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^1.0.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

What is wrong? Thank you in advance..

Comment: Have you tried `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js` or `node scripts/deploy.js` if not please run and see if it is working or throwing the same error. And share errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have found similar problem while searching. See if this solution works for you.

[MODULE_NOT_FOUND](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/30706)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing hardhat using
`npm install --dev hardhat`
If you not need that particular version, otherwise the issue might be specific to the version itself

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround to the Module_Not_Found compiling error.
https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/3176

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).